# Azure CD with publish profile

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I am currently learning Azure DevOps using a student account, which limits the permissions I have. Due to these restrictions, I am unable to use the normal deployment methods in Azure DevOps as I do not have access to Active Directory to make changes.

My current workaround is to use a Publish Profile. However, when I try to configure my release pipeline to deploy using this profile, I get the following error: "Error: Error : No such deploying method exists".

I am new to using Azure DevOps and do not understand why this error is occurring. Is there another solution for people like me who have access restrictions due to their school affiliation? Thank you for your help.

[My Release pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crMqr.png)

[Logs 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7hL8.png)

[logs 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Y9TS.png)
............................................................

Comment: Up...........................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a same issue with the same error message: [Publish Profile with method ZipDeploy returns "No such deploying method exists"](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/18538)

After checking [the source code of the Azure App Service deploy task](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/b521eabe5e8142a25f5d9f2b7ad360c16bc2bf45/Tasks/AzureRmWebAppDeploymentV4/operations/AzureAppServiceUtility.ts#L74), I found the `PublishProfile` option from Azure App Service Deploy task supports only `MSDeploy` publish method.

It checks if the `publishMethod` attribute is set to "`MSDeploy`". If no suitable `publishMethod` is found, it will reject with an error message indicating that the deploying method does not exist.

So, if you want to use the Connection Type Publish Profile, you need to make sure that the `WebPublishMethod` is set to `MSDeploy` in your Publish Profile.